# PHP mysqli query results garbled or missing when stored in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

In PHP, I am trying to query a mysqli db and put it into an array.

Here is my code:

```
        function get_hotlist_array() {
                include 'initvars.inc.php';
                $hotlistsql='select plate from hotlist where notifyPOCUID =1 ;';
                $hotlistlink = set_up_mysql_link ();  //custom function to set up the link
                $hotlistarray = mysqli_query($hotlistlink, $hotlistsql);
                print_r($hotlistarray);
                return $hotlistarray;
        } // End function get_hotlist_array
```

To test the contents of the array $hotlistarray you can see the print_r function above.  It yields the following results:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 12 [type] => 0 )
```

**num_rows = 12?  That's good!

Using MySQL WorkBench, I perform the same query and here are my results:

Query:

```
select plate from hotlist where notifyPOCUID =1 ;
```

Results

```
B0JAMS
HVT2701
HLG5574
BNT6417
KSL0854
KLS4012
JWN1809
CMV4859
NZN4319
NXX3035
65DV21
KXJ2991
```

There are indeed 12 rows in the results.  So that is encouraging!  But neither print_r nor var_dump show the actual values that I should be in the array $hotlistarray.

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

Here is the corrected code.

```
        function get_hotlist_array() {
                include 'initvars.inc.php';
                $hotlistsql='select plate from hotlist where notifyPOCUID =1 ;';
                $hotlistlink = set_up_mysql_link ();
                $tempresult = mysqli_query($hotlistlink, $hotlistsql);
                if ($tempresult !== false) {
                        $hotlistarray = $tempresult->fetch_all();
                } // End if tempresult is false
                print_r($hotlistarray);
                return $hotlistarray;
        } // End function get_hotlist_array
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the results.

If you want an associative array use:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hotlistarray)
```

If you run var_dump($row) you should see the results now.